# Broken padlock in Chrome on many SSL websites

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

Since yesterday I have a strange problem in Chrome. A broken padlock ('Mixed content' warning) is shown on many SSL websites (including my own, or https://www.bankofamerica.com/ ). The warning is always the same:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.bankofamerica.com/' was loaded
>   over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image
>   'http://xa.xingcloud.com/v4/security-protection/ae01c13c94a7ba3cbeed?action0=pay.status.injectjs.error%2C0&_ts=1421349365981'.
>   This content should also be served over HTTPS.

I cleared the browser cache, restarted. Nothing works. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a Chrome extension called "Security Protection". It installed without my permission, seems to be malware. After deleting it, everything works again.